# Can a voltage at a GPIO pin with no mode set harm the pi

Tags: gpio, pi-2

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B, and I plan on using the GPIO pins to detect whether a voltage is present or not. However, the circuit that controls the voltage levels runs independently from the pi, and I just wanted to know if a 3v3 at the pins could harm the pi if the GPIO pins aren't specifically in use, or the pi is turned off/loses power.

Comment: Please define "logic level voltage". Anything over 3.3V will kill your RPi. Information on the circuit/device that controls the voltage might get you a more detailed answer. There are numerous methods for limiting the device output to a safe level, but the right one "depends": voltage dividers, zener diodes, opto-isolators...

Comment: logic level voltage would be 3v3. I will edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If unconfigured GPIO pins are Inputs, so safe for a logic input 0 - 3.3V

If Output and opposite voltage is applied they can be damaged - which is why you should use a series resistor to limit current to a safe level.